# How can I return a promise or failure?

Tags: javascript, express, es6-promise

I want to write a Thennable function. Based on its parameters it might return a promise. Or it might discover that the parameters are bad, and then it wants to return something that will break the promise chain. What would that something be? Here is the sketch of my function as it stands.

```
function getThumbnailFromClips(res, clips) {
  var clips = content.clips;
  if (clips.length == 0) {
    res.status(400).send(new Error("Empty playlist"))
    // >> RETURN WHAT?  <<
  } else {
    var pick1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * clips.length);
    var sql1 = ` SELECT  <details omitted>   `;
    let promise = client.query(sql1)
    return promise
  }
}
```

It is called from an app.post callback, something like:

```
app.post("/foo", (req,res)=>{
  getClips(req)
  .then((clips)=>getThumbnailFromClips(res,clips))
  .then(((result)=>createDatabaseEntry(result)))
  .catch(/*etc*/)
})
```

Also, would it be better form to let the outermost caller take care of sending the 400 result code?

Comment: Return a *rejected* promise…?

Comment: I would say it is better to manage res in outer most caller. res in controller, function in service and routes will take care of all tha paths. As we are in 2023, It is better to use async...await and wrap the controller func with try...catch

Comment: `throw new Error('something went wrong')`

Comment: The whole design where you sometimes send a response and sometimes return something different is really just not a good design choice.  Return a rejected promise and have the caller send the error response when they get an error back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole design where you sometimes send a response and sometimes return something completely different is really just not a good design choice. You want a consistent return value.  If you're sometimes returning a promise, then ALWAYS return a promise.  Errors can be communicated back via a rejected promise.

Similarly, you don't want request handler code paths that sometimes send a response in one place and then sometimes send a response in another place.  It gets very hard to maintain the code so that you always send one and only one response and that all errors are handled consistently.  I would recommend that you don't send a response in the sub-functions you call, but instead centralize the sending of a response in the main request handler code.  So, the job of the sub-functions is to carry out some operation and return a result.  The job of the request handler body is to coordinate the sub-functions, get their result and send a response.

I would recommend something like this:

```
function getThumbnailFromClips(clips) {
    const clips = content.clips;
    if (clips.length == 0) {
        const err = new Error("Empty playlist");
        err.status = 400;
        return Promise.reject(err);
    } else {
        const pick1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * clips.length);
        const sql1 = ` SELECT  <details omitted>   `;
        return client.query(sql1);
    }
}

app.post("/foo", (req, res) => {
    getClips(req)
        .then(getThumbnailFromClips)
        .then(createDatabaseEntry)
        .then(() => {
            // send whatever the success status is supposed to be here
            res.send({status: "ok"});
        }).catch(err => {
            // all errors funnel to here
            const status = err.status || 500;
            res.status(status).send(err);
        });
});
```

And, `var` is basically obsolete now.  Use `const` or `let` instead.

Comment: Thanks.  Promise.reject was what I needed to know.